# Limit Records in a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, landing-page, smart-capture

I created a landing for customers to sign up for an event. This smart capture add and update a data extension. Our goal is only get the first 300 records.

Is it possible that when the Data Extension arrives at a quantity of records, we closed Data Extension or the Smart Capture no add a record after 300 records in data extension is populate?;

I noticed that i can't exclude the Landing Page in a date schedule. Only schedule the publish. I think if i can exclude the Landing Page in a determined day it's ok for me.;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the data extension limit, you can wrap the whole page and logic inside an AMPscript block. This block would lookup to your DE and if count is greater then 300 then show the 'sorry maximum has been met' content, otherwise show the form.

Example:

```
%%[ SET @myDE = 'myDEName'
SET @DErowcount = DataExtensionRowcount(@myDE)

IF @DErowcount > 300 THEN ]%%

    <p>sorry maximum has been met</p>

%%[ ELSE ]%%

    <!-- your current form and content here -->

%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Now this does work best when you have the form Posting to itself, as this will prevent it from going over 300 definitively. With it posting elsewhere, you do run the small risk of say 5 people loading the form when the count is at 299, then all five would be able to submit, putting you at 304, instead of 300.

You can also set this as a date too, if you would prefer a date defined expiry.

```
%%[ 
SET @currentDate = Now()

IF @currentDate >= "01/30/2019 12:00AM" THEN ]%%

    <p>sorry this page has expired</p>

%%[ ELSE ]%%

    <!-- your current form and content here -->

%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```